# Get list of elements having the specific "Requirement X" comment on elements

Tags: clearcase

I would like to get the list of elements of "`myvob/project/`" having the comment "`Requirement X`" with `cleartool` command.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a "cleartool find" query ready for that.

You could combine a cleartool find with the exec part to describe each element with their full name and comment, and then grep on the relevant comment.

See [additional find examples](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425):

#### Find a particular string in a comment by searching all versions of all elements in a VOB.

> Note: Example syntax includes formatting for the version and the comment:
>
> UNIX/Linux:

```
cleartool find -all -ver "! lbtype(<non-existing label>)" \
-exec 'cleartool desc -fmt "Version: %n\tComment: %c\n\n" $CLEARCASE_XPN' \
| grep <the string you are looking for>
```

> Windows:

```
cleartool find -all -ver "! lbtype(<non-existing label>)" \ 
-exec "cleartool desc -fmt \"Version: %n\tComment: %c\n\n\" %CLEARCASE_XPN%" \ 
| findstr "<the string you are looking for>"
```

Comment: Where can I specify the path "\myvob\project\" , Since i'm only looking it for specific project instead full vob

Comment: @srinannapa: replace the `-all` by your path, and you will limit the find query to a specif path within a Vob instead of all the Vobs.